# Who is the Queen of Heaven in the The Cowherd and the Weaver Girl?

Tags: chinese, goddesses

In the [The Cowherd and the Weaver Girl](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cowherd_and_the_Weaver_Girl) classic of ancient China, who exactly is the Queen of Heaven?

Is it [Doumu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doumu) or [The Queen Mother of the West](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Mother_of_the_West) or [Wusheng Laomu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wusheng_Laomu)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question: the Weaver girl is the daughter of the [Jade Emperor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jade_Emperor) therefore his wife must be the Jade Empress, the Queen Mother of the West, even though it's not stated in the story itself.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved with a citation!